# Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses

Tags: twig, task-parallel-library

I am trying to convert from .tpl to .twig. While converting the input types i am getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" .....

```html
    <input type="text" name="delta_{{ language['language_id'] }}" value="{{ {{'delta_' . language['language_id']}} is defined ? }}'delta_' ~ {{% set language['language_id'] '' = 'undefined' %}}" placeholder="{{ entry_delta }}" id="input-delta-{{ language['language_id'] }}" class="form-control" />
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You got the tenary operator's syntax wrong

```
<input type="text" name="delta_{{ language['language_id'] }}" value="delta_{{ language['language_id'] is defined ?  language['language_id']  : 'undefined'  }}" placeholder="{{ entry_delta }}" id="input-delta-{{ language['language_id'] }}" class="form-control" />
```

Also if you're just want to assure the variable exists, go with the [`default`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html) filter e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="delta_{{ language['language_id']|default('undefined') }}" value="delta_{{ language['language_id']|default('undefined')  }}" placeholder="{{ entry_delta }}" id="input-delta-{{ language['language_id']|default('undefined') }}" class="form-control" />
```